# what does yield without value do in context manager

Tags: python, generator, yield, contextmanager

```
import contextlib
import time

@contextlib.contextmanager
def time_print(task_name):
    t = time.time()
    try:
        yield
    finally:
        print task_name, "took", time.time() - t, "seconds."


def doproc():
    x=1+1


with time_print("processes"):
    [doproc() for _ in range(500)]

# processes took 15.236166954 seconds.
```

when does doproc get executed when using this decorator?

Comment: [From the docs:](https://docs.python.org/2/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.contextmanager) "At the point where the generator yields, the block nested in the with statement is executed. The generator is then resumed after the block is exited. If an unhandled exception occurs in the block, it is reraised inside the generator at the point where the yield occurred."

Comment: `yield` without argument is semantically equivalent to `yield None`

Answer (score 66):

`yield` expression returns control to the whatever is using the generator. The generator *pauses* at this point, which means that the `@contextmanager` decorator knows that the code is done with the *setup* part.

In other words, everything you want to do in the context manager `__enter__` phase has to take place before the `yield`.

Once your context exits (so the block under the `with` statement is done), the `@contextmanager` decorator is called for the `__exit__` part of the context manager protocol and will do one of two things:

- If there was no exception, it'll resume your generator. So your generator unpauses at the `yield` line, and you enter the *cleanup phase*, the part
- If there was an exception, the decorator uses `generator.throw()` to raise that exception in the generator. It'll be as if the `yield` line caused that exception. Because you have a `finally` clause, it'll be executed before your generator exits because of the exception.

So, in your specific example the sequence is as follows:

1. `with time_print("processes"):`

   This creates the context manager and calls `__enter__` on that.
2. The generator starts execution, `t = time.time()` is run.
3. The `yield`expression pauses the generator, control goes back to the decorator. This takes whatever was yielded and returns that to the `with` statement, in case there is an `as target` part. Here `None` is yielded (there is only a plain `yield` expression).
4. `[doproc() for _ in range(500)]` is run and completes.
5. The context manager `__exit__` method is run, no exception is passed in.
6. The decorator resumes the generator, it continues where it left off.
7. The `finally:` block is entered and `print task_name, "took", time.time() - t, "seconds."` is executed.
8. The generator exits, the decorator `__exit__` method exits, all is done.

Comment: I do not understand the phrase  "This takes whatever was yielded". But `yield` is without parameter. It did not 'yield' anything...

Comment: @Alex: you always yield *something*. That can be `None`, just like `return` exits a function and the return value is then `None`. But you can also yield something explicitly, so `yield some_object`, at which point that value can be assigned to a target with the `with context_manager as <target>` syntax.

Answer (score 11):

Excellent explanation by @Martijn Pieters. Since the **yield** is redundant in your case, you can achieve the same by creating your own context manager (without **yield** and **contextlib.contextmanager**). This is simpler and more readable. So in your case you can implement something as follows.

```
import time

class time_print(object):
    def __init__(self, task_name):
        self.task_name = task_name

    def __enter__(self):
        self.t = time.time()

    def __exit__(self):
        print self.task_name, "took", time.time() - self.t, "seconds."

def doproc():
    x = 1 + 1


with time_print("processes"):
    # __enter__ is called
    [doproc() for _ in range(500)]
    # __exit__ is called
```

Internally **contextlib.contextmanager** calls these ****enter**** and ****exit**** magic functions as explained by @Martijn-Pieters. Hope this helps!

Comment: This is not really "simpler and more readable" because you need to declare a class with three methods rather than a single function. Also, your code doesn’t work if there is an exception inside the `with` because the signature of `__exit__` is wrong: it must take three more arguments. This is something you don’t have to worry about with `@contextmanager`.