# yield in contextlib.contextmanager

Tags: python, python-3.x, contextmanager

Why can I skip calling log_func in `yield log_func`, i.e. I can just write `yield` and the code still works. Why is that? How does `yield` work in this case?

```
import time
from contextlib import contextmanager

@contextmanager
def log_exec(log_func):
    s = time.perf_counter()
    yield log_func
    e = time.perf_counter()
    log_func(e - s)

with log_exec(log.debug):
    time.sleep(1)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Excerpt from the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.contextmanager):

> This `iterator` must `yield` exactly one value, which will be **bound to the targets** in the `with` statement’s `as` clause, if any.

You are not using `as` clause, therefore the outcome is unchanged. But if you try to use it with an empty `yield`, you will see that the yielded value is `None`.

```
with log_exec(debug) as log_foo:
    print(log_foo)
    time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: So in this case, since the contextmanager requires an iterator, we have to yield, even though we're yielding nothing? This is probably more of a question about the implementation of this contextmanager.

Comment: Yes, we have to yield exactly one value, even `None`. You can read more in this excellent [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35489897/13782669)