# Why a python's yield does not require a 2nd call to resume?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have some python code :

```python
# file: your_app/views.py
import contextlib
import inspect

from airium import Airium
from django.http import HttpResponse


@contextlib.contextmanager
def basic_body(a: Airium, useful_name: str = ''):
    """Works like a Django/Ninja template."""

    a('<!DOCTYPE html>')
    with a.html(lang='en'):
        with a.head():
            a.meta(charset='utf-8')
            a.meta(content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1', name='viewport')
            # do not use CSS from this URL in a production, it's just for an educational purpose
            a.link(href='https://unpkg.com/@picocss/pico@1.4.1/css/pico.css', rel='stylesheet')
            a.title(_t=f'Hello World')

        with a.body():
            with a.div():
                with a.nav(klass='container-fluid'):
                    with a.ul():
                        with a.li():
                            with a.a(klass='contrast', href='./'):
                                a.strong(_t="⌨ Foo Bar")
                    with a.ul():
                        with a.li():
                            a.a(klass='contrast', href='#', **{'data-theme-switcher': 'auto'}, _t='Auto')
                        with a.li():
                            a.a(klass='contrast', href='#', **{'data-theme-switcher': 'light'}, _t='Light')
                        with a.li():
                            a.a(klass='contrast', href='#', **{'data-theme-switcher': 'dark'}, _t='Dark')

                with a.header(klass='container'):
                    with a.hgroup():
                        a.h1(_t=f"You're on the {useful_name}")
                        a.h2(_t="It's a page made by our automatons with a power of steam engines.")

            with a.main(klass='container'):
                yield  # This is the point where main content gets inserted

            with a.footer(klass='container'):
                with a.small():
                    margin = 'margin: auto 10px;'
                    a.span(_t='© Airium HTML generator example', style=margin)

            # do not use JS from this URL in a production, it's just for an educational purpose
            a.script(src='https://picocss.com/examples/js/minimal-theme-switcher.js')


def index(request) -> HttpResponse:
    a = Airium()
    with basic_body(a, f'main page: {request.path}'):
        with a.article():
            a.h3(_t="Hello World from Django running Airium")
            with a.p().small():
                a("This bases on ")
                with a.a(href="https://picocss.com/examples/company/"):
                    a("Pico.css / Company example")

            with a.p():
                a("Instead of a HTML template, airium has been used.")
                a("The whole body is generated by a template "
                  "and the article code looks like that:")

            with a.code().pre():
                a(inspect.getsource(index))

    return HttpResponse(bytes(a))  # from django.http import HttpResponse
```

This code uses a **yield** so the **basic_body** can be shared accross multiple pages and the **main** is filled according to the need of the specific page.

I thought that in order to resume a yielded function you had to call it again ([see here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/use-yield-keyword-instead-return-keyword-python/)), but I cannot see a 2nd call to **basic_body** here. What's going on? And how does the **yield** resume works?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35489844/what-does-yield-without-value-do-in-context-manager

Comment: Also for the basics of generators (not specific to this particular specialised usage with @contextmanager): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1756096/understanding-generators-in-python. The geeks4geeks article you link to doesn't really explain some fundamental concepts properly. Particularly, it doesn't make it clear that *calling a generator function returns a generator object*.

Answer (score 1):

Your examples don't call the function multiple times. They call the function once, which returns a generator, and then they iterate over that single generator (e.g. `for value in simpleGeneratorFun():`) which behind the scenes calls `.__next__()` repeatedly so that the function resumes and yields again until it's done.

In this case, consuming the generator is done by the `@contextlib.contextmanager` decorator.

Below is the relevant source code:

```py
def contextmanager(func):
    # The @contextmanager decorator replaces `basic_body` with `helper`
    @wraps(func)
    def helper(*args, **kwds):
        # Calling basic_body calls `helper` which returns this thing
        return _GeneratorContextManager(func, args, kwds)
    return helper

class _GeneratorContextManager(...):
    # Using a `with` statement calls __enter__ at the beginning
    def __enter__(self):
        try:
            # `next()` is iteration, it runs the generator until the yield
            return next(self.gen)
        except StopIteration:
            raise RuntimeError("generator didn't yield") from None

    # __exit__ is called when the `with` block finishes
    def __exit__(self, typ, value, traceback):
        # If there was no exception...
        if typ is None:
            try:
                # Try iterating again
                next(self.gen)
            except StopIteration:
                # StopIteration means no more yield, which is good
                return False
            else:
                # The iteration didn't end, so there was another yield, not allowed in contextmanager
                raise RuntimeError("generator didn't stop")
```